# Image in Reportviewer

Tags: c#, reportviewer

I need to display Images in a C# ReportViewer

The Image Source is set as "External".

The trick is that the SourcePath for the Image needs to be generated at runtime based on fields in a Tablix in the Body of the Report.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your data source is for your report, but I work with DataTables in my reports.

In those with images, I add a data column of

```
DataColumn column = new DataColumn("someImg");
column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Byte[]");
column.AllowDBNull = true;
MyDataTable.Columns.Add(column);
```

Then, for each row, such as the row has a file name of the actual image instead of an actual image column in the table having the data, I populate this column by

```
foreach( DataRow dr in MyDataTable.Rows )
   dr["someImg"] = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(dr["FullPathAndFileToActual.jpg"] );
```

So, since you will know the path at run-time, just adjust the loop to find the images like I have here, then run with the report.

Then each row has a valid binary graphic object that can be presented on a per row basis.

In the report, make sure the "General" section of your image control has the proper "MIMEType" setting, my source was set to "Database", and value set to =Fields!someImg.Value.